# Problems with subfolder emails - sugarcrm

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, sugarcrm

When I move read emails from inbox to a subfolder, it appears as unread email. I would like to move both the email status (read or unread) to subfolder. How can I achieve this? Will this be done in javascript or PHP.

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted this out..in the moveEmails function in InboundEmail.php, change

```
$email = new Email();
$email->retrieve($id);
$email->status = 'unread'

to

$email = new Email();
$email->retrieve($id);
$email->status = 'read'
```